# Matplotlib and numpy histogram2d axis issue

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, histogram2d

I'm struggling to get the axis right:

I've got the `x` and `y` values, and want to plot them in a 2d histogram (to examine correlation). Why do I get a histogram with limits from 0-9 on each axis? How do I get it to show the actual value ranges?

This is a minimal example and I would expect to see the red "star" at `(3, 3)`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3)
y = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3)
xedges = range(5)
yedges = range(5)
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(y, x)
im = plt.imshow(H, origin='low')
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram2d]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is twofold:

Firstly you should have 5 bins in your histogram (it's set to 10 as default):

```
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(y, x,bins=5)
```

Secondly, to set the axis values, you can use the `extent` parameter, as per [the `histogram2d` man pages](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html):

```
im = plt.imshow(H, interpolation=None, origin='low',
                extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just need to set `interpolation='none'`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3)
y = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3)
xedges = range(5)
yedges = range(5)
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(y, x)
im = plt.imshow(H, origin='low', interpolation='none')
```

[image]

Does that look right?

Comment: Not really, the red square is still at (5,5) and want the scales so that they're reflecting the actual data values. The red square should be at (3,3).

Comment: It is both, you need `extent` + `interoplation='none'`